# Issue in asp.net core model classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my model class.
In `RootObject` class I have a list of `Trans` class. In ASP.NET Core when I am passing values to `RootObject` from Postman I am getting null in `RootObject`.

```
public class Trans
{
    public string SubDetailID { get; set; }
    public string TrnType { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
    public string BankCurrencyRate { get; set; }
    public decimal AccountID { get; set; }
    public string Currency { set; get; }
    public string CurrencyRate { set; get; }
    public decimal JVID { get; set; }
    public string coa { get; set; }
    public decimal BusinessID { get; set; }

}

public class RootObject
{
    public int JVID { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceRef { get; set; }
    public DateTime JVDate { get; set; }
    public string StoreID { get; set; }
    public decimal BusinessID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; } = "Client";
    public decimal RefID { get; set; }
    public string Narration { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } = "CA";
    public virtual List<Trans> transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's only a data structure, without any operations. Something like a Postman is not defined.

Comment: show us an example of the postman call, these are only classes.

Comment: Also include _in y our question_ the code where you are seeing the null values and the details of the Postman request.